# In differentiation can you prove the product rule using the sum rule by breaking apart the product

Tags: solution-verification, products, differential, fake-proofs

for example if you let
$f(x)=g(x)h(x)$

then $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=g(x)+g(x)+g(x)...$ appearing $h(x)$ amount of times

therefore using the *sum rule*, $f'(x)$ can be written as
$f'(x)=g'(x)+g'(x)+g'(x)...$

where $g'(x)$ appears $h(x)$ amount of times, therefore:
$f'(x)=g'(x)h(x)$

same applies for the other way of $f'(x)=h'(x)+h'(x)+h'(x)...$ so $f'(x)=h'(x)g(x)$

but the product rule is $f'(x)=g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x)$

therefore how can this be shown using this reasoning with the *sum rule*, or where have I gone wrong in my reasoning so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you add $x$ to itself $\sqrt2$ times? $\pi$ times? That’s the most important error. The next error is that you’re treating $h(x)$ as a constant in the first argument, which of course it is not.

Comment: Right, but the form is very similar to the actual answer, which makes me believe that there might be a way of reasoning to get it since its just g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x) added together or is that wishful thinking

Comment: (Not sure if this is helpful) One possible way is to approach it as if it's an area.  $f( x + \delta_ x) = g( x + \delta_ x ) h ( x + \delta_ x) = [ g(x) + g'(x) \delta_ x ] [ g(x) + h'(x) \delta_ x] = g(x)h(x) + \delta_ x ( g'(x) h(x) + g(x) h'(x) ] + (\delta_ x)^2 g'(x) h'(x) $ What can we say about the rate of change of each of these?

Comment: Draw a picture of a rectangle with length $g(x)$ and height $h(x)$ Change $x$ by $\Delta x$. Then what are the new length, new height, and the change in the area?

Comment: In "Calculus" 2nd Ed. Volume 1, Tom Apostol proves the product rule by going back to basics, via the definition of the derivative : $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

Comment: "$f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=g(x)+g(x)+g(x)...$ appearing $h(x)$ amount of times" is not sound mathematics when $h(x)$ is not an integer. Unfortunately there's no way to recover anything like this.